# How to set the amount of elements that will be fetched from backend by a DataProvider?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

I want to lazy load some data from a grid into my Vaadin View. The grid rows are sometimes pretty huge so I want to limit the amount of rows that are loaded at once let's say to 2.

I tried to do this using `DataProvider.fromCallbacks()`. Unfortunately I am not getting the result I wish for and I am a bit confused about the two functions that are passed into the method.

As far as I am understanding it correctly the first function that is passed describes how the items are fetched and the second function tells the DataProvider the maximal possible amount of items that can be fetched.

> fromCallbacks(CallbackDataProvider.FetchCallback
>   fetchCallback, CallbackDataProvider.CountCallback
>   countCallback) Creates a new data provider that uses callbacks for
>   fetching and counting items from any backing store.

I tried the following but it always leads to a lot of items fetched. (17 items in list leads to 17 items fetched, 120 items in list leads to 50's batches)

```
    List<SomeObject> data = ... // filled with objects

    DataProvider<CustromCell, Void> lazyLoadingProvider
            = DataProvider.fromCallbacks(
                    query -> {
                        int offset = query.getOffset();
                        int limit = query.getLimit(); // Is this the amount of items that are fetched in one step?

                        if (offset + limit > data.size()) 
                            return data.stream();

                        List<CustromCell> cells = data.subList(offset,offset+limit); 
                                                                 //(offest,offset+2) crashes
                        return cells.stream()
                    },
                    query -> data.size() // Max possible items to fetch
            );
            grid.setDataProvider(lazyLoadingProvider);
```

Has the following behavior:

```
Size Of Data: 219
Offset: 0
Limit: 50

Size Of Data: 219
Offset: 50
Limit: 50

Size Of Data: 219
Offset: 100
Limit: 50

Size Of Data: 219
Offset: 150
Limit: 50

Size Of Data: 219
Offset: 200
Limit: 19
```

I have to call `getOffset()` and `getLimit()` of the Query object otherwise an exception is thrown. If I understand it correctly then the limit tells how many items shall be fetched (the goal would be 2 in my case) but the object is immutable so I can't change this value ([Query API](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.13/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/Query.html))?

**tl;dr** How can I tell the DataProvider to only fetch 2 items of my grid at once?

**Edit**: I found github issues related to my issue ([#6072](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6072), [#3830](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/3830))

**Edit 2**: A github issue was merged so it is more clear how the getLimit() method works: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6996

Comment: In SQL, the `LIMIT` resticts the fetching to a specified amount of rows, so I guess the limit you can set in that code is that SQL `LIMIT`. Have you tried to set it instead of getting an obviously unkown and/or unset amount? I mean instead of `int limit = query.getLimit();` you could do `int limit = 100`;, for example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this.

The `query.getLimit()` method is depending on the component's (so the Grid's) pagesize.

Quoting the [Grid API](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.13/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html):

> Grid()
>
> Creates a new instance, with page size of 50.

My grid was initialized like this: `Grid a = new Grid();` which leads to a pagesize of 50. `query.getLimit()` will return 50 in this case.

> Grid(int pageSize)
>
> Creates a new instance, with the specified page size.

Initializing the grid like this: `Grid a = new Grid(5);`. `query.getLimit()` will now return 5 in this case and the `DataProvider` will fetch only the next 5 elements.

**Edit**: A github issue regarding this SO question was merged: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6996

Answer (score 1):

To be more exact, the query limit depends on 2 main criteria:

- **the page size** setup on your grid (as you already found)
- and - in the case you are using a data provider - the **data provider size**

And 2 other secondary criteria / behavior:

- **How many elements you can display at a time in your UI**. If your grid can display more than the page size setup at a time, then the query limit will automatically adapt based on the data provider size and what i guess the default page size (50)
- As **the grid may alter your query limit** depending on what i've just explained, if you refresh your data (because you apply filtering on the data provider for example), your limit won't be the grid page size anymore, unless you specifically set it again before refreshing the data, example:

  > ```
  > grid.setPageSize(GRID_PAGE_SIZE);
  > grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
  > ```

Thus, let say your data provider return 34 results, you have set a page size of 5 and you display unlimited number of results in your UI, you will have the following behavior:

1. Fetch the first 5 (page size setup) elements
2. Found that you can display more elements on the UI, so trigger a second fetch on the data provider
3. Fetch from offset 5 to limit 34

I found this combination is not documented at all..